# Hammer.js - simple realization "Drag & Drop" DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Prompt how to implement a simple drag and drop with Hammer.js.** 1 DIV:

```
<div class="first"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var element = $('.first').get(0);        
var hammertime = new Hammer(element);
        hammertime.on('pan', function(e) {
            var tapX, tapY;
            tapX = e.center.x;
            tapY = e.center.y;

            this.style.left = tapX;
            this.style.top = tapY;
        });
```

I need to make this div I could move around the screen. At the moment I would not succeed. The situation is not complicated, I just could not find even the simplest implementation, move the block, I would appreciate if you can help me to implement a simple drag and drop.

http://jsfiddle.net/0fawast9/

Answer (score 1):

I am seeking for a simple drag & drop solution too, and found your post.

It seems that hammer 1.1.3 not firing "pan" event. Also, "this" in the event listener refers to the function itself, and left/top uses string with "px". I modified your code a bit

```
var element = $('.first').get(0);        
var hammertime = new Hammer(element);
    hammertime.on('pan', function(e) {
        var tapX, tapY;
        tapX = e.center.x;
        tapY = e.center.y;
        console.log(tapX + ' --- ' + tapY);

        element.style.left = tapX + "px";
        element.style.top = tapY + "px";
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0fawast9/11/

Hope can help you despite the question is asked a year ago :)